# How can I make a webpage readable on desktop and mobile without screwing with font size?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'd like to be able to format my blog in a way that is usable for both desktop and mobile without attempting to detect mobile browsers. As a fan of web standards, I would think that if I used just basic HTML with no styling at all, it should be usable, but it turns out both iPhone and Android browsers render with tiny text (apparently to duplicate the layout that would be seen on desktop browsers).

I am aware I can use media queries and a dozen other techniques to get the appearance I want on mobile browsers. I'm interested in knowing if there is any way to get a mobile browser to display something at the devices default font size without resorting to font-size: 20pt; in a stylesheet. Is there any kind of "yes, this is just plain HTML, so don't try to pretend you have a desktop browser's width"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `viewport` `meta` does wonders for mobile devices. This will make the viewport the size of the device rather than trying to make it bigger and scaling it down:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

You may see other versions of this with `width=device-width` and such. That will work, but it will also scale up your web page when it is in landscape mode (which I find undesirable). Using all these scale constraints will make sure that the viewport is the appropriate size for both orientations.

Apple, who created the `viewport` `meta`, has [documentation on it](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/html/const/viewport).